# multiple left join if item has many (dynamic) attributes

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables, products and pattributes. Each product can have many pattributes!

Problem starts when i have to find product with multiple pattributes.

```
select * from `products` 
left join `pattributes` on `pattributes`.`products_id` = `products`.`id` 
where `products`.`status` = 1 
AND `products`.`sold` = 0 
AND `products`.`deleted` = 0 
AND `products`.`categories_id` = 30 
AND `pattributes`.`attributes_id` = 5 
AND `pattributes`.`values_id` = 10 
AND `pattributes`.`attributes_id` = 4 
AND `pattributes`.`values_id` = 15 
group by `products`.`id` 
order by `products`.`top` desc, 
`products`.`id` desc
```

So if i'm looking for two or more pattributes it returns 0 rows. But if i look for one pattribute it works fine.

I'm not an mysql guru, not sure if i have to do it with left join. Maybe someone knows best solution for it?

Added SQL Fiddle - maybe it would be easier http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3ada0

Comment: Right join is not working too.

Comment: you check for a specific relation to have both attributes, even though a relation through `join` is one to one, try `in` instead.

Comment: A possible solution would be to do a subquery where you retrieve a count of all matching attribute rows (`where (foo = 1 and bar = 5) or (foo = 2 and bar = 17)`), and in the outer query validate that number to be equal to the number of attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally with some friends help got it working:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    `products`
WHERE 
    `products`.`status` = 1 
    AND `products`.`sold` = 0 
    AND `products`.`deleted` = 0 
    AND `products`.`categories_id` = 30
    AND 
    (
        (SELECT 
             COUNT(*) 
         FROM `pattributes`
         WHERE 
             `pattributes`.`products_id` = `products`.`id`
             AND 
             (
                 (
                   `pattributes`.`attributes_id` = 4
                   AND `pattributes`.`values_id` = 14
                 )
                 OR
                 (
                   `pattributes`.`attributes_id` = 5
                   AND `pattributes`.`values_id` = 10
                 )
             )
         ) = 2

    )
GROUP BY `products`.`id`
ORDER BY `products`.`top` DESC, `products`.`id` DESC
```

Comment: This is not going to be very efficient though.

Answer (score 0):

Use `IN()` for multiple pattributes and same as for multiple `values_id`

```
select * from `products` 
left join `pattributes` on `pattributes`.`products_id` = `products`.`id` 
where `products`.`status` = 1 
AND `products`.`sold` = 0 
AND `products`.`deleted` = 0 
AND `products`.`categories_id` = 30 
AND `pattributes`.`attributes_id` IN(5 ,4)// if type is varchar then IN('5' ,'4')
AND `pattributes`.`values_id` IN( 10,15 )
group by `products`.`id` 
order by `products`.`top` desc, 
`products`.`id` desc
```

Comment: @user1341104 This will either give you incorrect results, matching (5, 10), (5, 15), (4, 10) and (4, 15), or `attributes_id` does not matter so it can be removed from the `where` clause.

Comment: Sorry mistake it is not working exactly as i wanted! attributes_id matter!